# how to Catch DeadLineExceedException in appengine/J?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I tried catching the DeadlineExceededException.

```
try
{
    Client restletClient  =  new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
    Request req    =  new Request(Method.GET, urltocall);
    Response res    =  restletClient.handle(req);
    log.info("The status of the response : " + res.getStatus());
    responseContent   =  res.getEntity().getText();
    log.info("Content is  : " + responseContent);
    }
    catch(DeadlineExceededException e)
    {
         log.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,e.getMessage(),e);
         log.info("Inside catch block send mail to client service team!");
         response.sendRedirect("/Messages");
    }
```

But, I am unable to catch. Is there any other way to catch?

Comment: _But, I am unable to catch_ what do you mean by it? is that exception really throwing in try block?

Comment: Yes i am able to get the exception like HardDeadlineExceedException
But the appengine api is providing only DeadLineExceedException so i am using the exception provided by the appengine api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two exceptions that we are talking about here : `DeadlineExceededException` and the `HardDeadlineExceededError`.

The `DeadlineExceededException` is thrown when you hit some limits for e.g. HTTP request calls should complete their processing within 60 seconds, etc. This is something that you can catch in your code.

However, when you catch that exception what it means is that you must finish your processing really quick (less than a second usually available), otherwise the `HardDeadlineExceededError` exception is thrown and you cannot catch that in your application.

So what is most likely happening is that you are able to catch that exception but your code is likely taking too much time to complete in the catch handler and hence the `HardDeadlineExceededError` is thrown. Sometimes, it can also happen when the App Engine runtime was too busy to be able to raise the `DeadlineExceededException` and as a result it simply threw the `HardDeadlineExceededError`, which you cannot catch.

Refer to https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors for more details.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the detailed explanation.
It is exactly i am getting runtime exception and then it is elevated to the HardDeadlineExceededError

Answer (score 0):

> But, I am unable to catch

Which means some either no exception is thrown or exception different than `DeadlineExceededException` is thrown.

> Is there any other way to catch?

Any catch block with `DeadlineExceededException` exception or any other exception more generic than `DeadlineExceededException` will handle this exception.

Comment: I am getting HardDeadLineExceedException for which i am trying to handle it using the DeadLineExceedException But is not caught.
Am I missing to handling it properly ?

Comment: @Sridhar: Really? Then just use it in catch block. I couldnt find that exception. Google it and check if you can find it.